# Edited features not appearing in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.2

In ArcGIS 10.2 I created multi-segment lines using the Editor. Once a line was drawn, I selected "Finish Sketch" and then "Saved Edits". My new line appears in the attribute table but not on the map. However, if I double click said line in the attribute table, the line appears as selected in the map but disappears upon removing my selection. Why don't my edits appear permenantly on the map?

Comment: What symbology rules are you using? Does your new line fall into those rules, or do you need to fill in some attributes to make it actually render?

Comment: You may need to build the Spatial Index. When features appear and disappear, this is usually the problem.

Comment: Is there a chance you have a definition query on your dataset?

Comment: Do you have a definition query running on that layer?

Answer (score 1):

In the properties of your layer (right click on it), you should go to the symbology snippets and check the box "all other values" for symbol by categories. If your feature is visible in the attribute table, this is not a "definition query" issue. So, most probably, your new features have a field value that does not exist in the current symbology.